# Add date under slider/grid featured content

Tags: customization, theme-twenty-fourteen

I'd like to add post date under slider/grid text (which is category+Title) in my twenty fourteen wordpress child theme.

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. As this is your first post, you should read [ask] to get some tips on asking a good question. Also, take time and read our [tour] page. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible and quite easy to achieve. Here is how

**STEP 1**

Copy *content-featured-post.php* to your child theme and open it up

**STEP 2**

Just after line 32, paste the following code

```
<?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>
```

Save this change, and your done

As you can see, [`get_the_date`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date) is used to return the post date

> The get_the_date template tag retrieves the date the current $post was written. Unlike the_date() this tag will always return the date.

To customize the date that is displayed, you can go and check out [Formatting Date and Time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)